# How to deploy from bitbucket to gcloud using OIDC?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid-connect, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to deploy from **bitbucket** to **google app engine** using **Open ID Connect** (OIDC) authentication method (not key file).

I've setup **Open ID Connect** in my bitbucket repository. It shows

- Identity provider URL
- Audience
- Example paylode
- Unique identifiers

I've setup a **Service Account** in GCP that has **App Engine Deployer** role.

I've setup **Workload Identity Federation** with a pool and a provider. The **Issuer(URL)** of provider is set to **Identity provider URL** of bitbucket OIDC.

I've granted the service account access to the pool.

Here is my deployment step in bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
- step:
  name: Deploy to Production
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  oidc: true
  script:
    - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > identity-token
    - gcloud auth login --cred-file clientLibraryConfig.json --update-adc
    - gcloud app deploy
```

The clientLibraryConfig.json is downloaded from GCP:

```
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/837282586571/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/fakfake-com/providers/bitbucket-fakfake-com",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/bitbucket@fakfake-com.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "credential_source": {
    "file": "identity-token",
    "format": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output from pipeline:

```
echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > identity-token

gcloud auth login --cred-file clientLibraryConfig.json --update-adc

+ gcloud auth login --cred-file ../../clientLibraryConfig.json --update-adc
Application default credentials (ADC) were updated.
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [bitbucket@fakfake-com.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Your current project is [fakfake-com].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID


gcloud app deploy

+ gcloud app deploy ../../app.yaml
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OAuthError): ('Error code invalid_grant: The audience in JWT does not match the expected values.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The audience in JWT does not match the expected values."}')
If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
    gcloud feedback
To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
    gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Build teardown
```

How can I fix the error of `gcloud app deploy`?

Comment: Your Workload Identity setup appears correct. I think you have hit a bug with the CLI for App Engine. If nobody responds on StackOverflow, create an issue here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers  I think this is breaking app deploy **"type": "external_account",**. Note: The last time I worked with Workload Identity, I used version 3.52. The current version is 3.65. It is possible something has broken since 3.52.

Comment: Issue created: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207800949

Comment: I am following this post and the issue. Please update once you have more information. Good luck ...